# How to upgrade a formula of Homebrew as a package developer?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have created a Homebrew tap which has a single formula to install my package `Foo`.

`Foo` is upgraded now, and I am wondering what I should do to upgrade the formula as well? In other words, what should I tell Homebrew, so users can run `brew upgrade`  to upgrade `Foo`?